# Python chained `yield form`

Tags: python, async-await

I was reading through this [article](https://snarky.ca/how-the-heck-does-async-await-work-in-python-3-5/) about async and await in python, and saw this sample code:

```
def bottom():
    # Returning the yield lets the value that goes up the call stack to come right back
    # down.
    return (yield 42)

def middle():
    return (yield from bottom())

def top():
    return (yield from middle())

# Get the generator.
gen = top()
value = next(gen)
print(value)  # Prints '42'.
try:
    value = gen.send(value * 2)
except StopIteration as exc:
    value = exc.value
print(value)  # Prints '84'.
```

I can understand the chaining generators to return `42`, but I can't seem to get my head around `gen.send(value * 2)` and get 84 back. I would have thought initial `next(gen)` would have already exhausted the generator as following experiment?

```
def bottom():
    # Returning the yield lets the value that goes up the call stack to come right back
    # down.
    return (yield 42)

def middle():
    return (yield from bottom())

def top():
    return (yield from middle())

# Get the generator.
gen = top()
value = next(gen)
print(value)  # Prints '42'.

value = next(gen)
print(value)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 16, in <module>
    value = next(gen)
StopIteration
```

Could someone please explain?

PS: Not the most well thought out title, someone please help fix it...

Comment: It did exhaust the iterator.  The iterator hard coded to only ever return `42`.  `value = gen.send(value * 2)` fails with `StopIteration` because `gen` is exhausted.  In the exception value is set *from the exception* (`value = exc.value`).  It looks like the exception holds on to the sent value.

Comment: Note that only the *first* `StopIteration` appears to carry the value sent by `send`; subsequent attempts merely raise a "plain" `StopIteration`.

Answer (score 1):

As @Steven Rumbalski already explained in the comment: The generator yields only one value - the 42. In the second call the iterator raises the `StopIteration`, which is caught by the `except __StopIteration__ as exc:`. So you are completely right in that the initial `next(gen)` has already exhausted the generator. The same holds true in your second example, but in this case you are not catching the `StopIteration` exception. For further reading I will quote from the PEP 380 -- Syntax for Delegating to a Subgenerator.

> Add a new *send()* method for generator-iterators, which resumes the generator and sends a value that becomes the result of the current yield-expression. The *send()* method returns the next value yielded by the generator, or raises **StopIteration** if the generator exits without yielding another value.

from [PEP342](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0342/#new-generator-method-send-value)

So why do you get 84 back with the `gen.send(value * 2)`? The value of `value` at this point is still 42 from the previous call of `value = next(gen)`. So you are just getting back the 84 that you wanted to sent to the iterator. Why is that?

Consider the following simplified examples to understand better what that definition means. First we only yield a single value. No returns. This results in an empty `StopIteration` with `value` attribute `None`.

```
def generator():
    yield 1

gen = generator()
value = next(gen)
print(value)  # Prints '1'.
try:
    value = gen.send(3)
except StopIteration as exc:
    value = exc.value
print(value)  # Prints 'None'.
```

> *return expr* in a generator causes **StopIteration***(expr)* to be raised upon exit from the generator.

from [PEP380](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/#enhancements-to-stopiteration)

Then we `return 2` after the generator yields no further values. In this case the rule from [PEP380](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/#enhancements-to-stopiteration) comes into play. As 2 was the returned value the `value` attribute of `StopIteration` is 2.

```
def generator():
    yield 1
    return 2

gen = generator()
value = next(gen)
print(value)  # Prints '1'.
try:
    value = gen.send(3)
except StopIteration as exc:
    value = exc.value
print(value)  # Prints '2'.
```

Now we `return (yield 1)`. According to the rule from [PEP342](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0342/#new-generator-method-send-value) the 3 as the value of `gen.send(3)` becomes the result of the current yield-expression. But since the generator is already exhausted the `StopIteration` exception is raised. Which leads to the 3 as the `value` of the raised `StopIteration`.

```
def generator():
    return (yield 1)

gen = generator()
value = next(gen)
print(value)  # Prints '1'.
try:
     value = gen.send(3)
except StopIteration as exc:
    value = exc.value
print(value)  # Prints '3'.
```